# Applying color only to the box i click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to apply colors to the label colorCheckBox, and they all have unique data-id
the data-id comes from `colorBoxId =  $(this).closest('tr').data('id');` a variable that is global. The problem is that instead of adding color to only one label at a time, it adds colors to all the labels at the same time.  I have a picture on the issue 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aThX1.png)

When I click the label this div will show

```
<div class="colorList" id="colorSelectFilter" style="display:none; padding: 20px;">
  <a href="#" data-value="1">Grön(Godkännn)<div class="greenBox"></div></a>
  <a href="#" data-value="2">Röd(Slå av)<div class="redBox"></div></a>
  <a href="#" data-value="3">Gul(Kontrollera)<div class="yellowBox"></div></a>
</div>
```

Then when I click on the colorSelectFilter this happens in jquery

```
const colors = [null, 'green', 'red', 'yellow'];
$("#colorSelectFilter").find('a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  const filter = parseInt($(this).data('value'));
  alert(colorBoxId + "Ska skickas till ajax!!");
  // Skapa en variabel utan för med noll som värde
  // som vi sen ska fylla med id från respektive id
  // SOm vi sen skickar iväg med ajax

  var totalColor = colors[filter];
  console.log(colors[filter] + "ErrandSelect");

  if (!isNaN(filter)) {
    // This is the problem; it adds color
    $('.colorCheckBox').css('background-color', colors[filter]); 
  }
});
```

What I want is to only add a color on the label im clicking on.  Any pointers would be nice.

Comment: can you show more of ur html code?
`$('.colorCheckBox').css` affects all elements of this class, you need to get the clicked element with something like this `$(this).css`

Comment: I agree with toffler, `$('.colorCheckBox')` is a global selector.  You will have to determine which one is related to the `<a>` you clicked.  From what you have provided so far, I'm not sure how we can answer definitively how you should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The `event` argument in the callback function has a property named `target` that refers to the element that was clicked, you can pass it via the jQuery function to work on it with jQuery, see example below.

```js
$('.foo').click(event => {
  $(event.target).css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">Div #1</div>
<div class="foo">Div #2</div>
<div class="foo">Div #3</div>
```